# Adding serial number to each record inserted in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, function, triggers

My need is very simple. How to add a serial number or id(probably an auto_increment value I guess) for each row being inserted in a MySQL table?

To be more specific, I've a CSV file from which I store the separate field values into the database using LOAD DATA. What all I need is, if there are totally 2000 rows being loaded from the CSV file, each row has to be automatically inserted with a unique serial number like 1,2,3,etc...

Please help me with the exact query that I'll be needing rather than a syntax.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to your id column (create it if you need to). It will then do this automatically for you:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. I tried that earlier but I had a problem in it.

Say I've a CSV file like the following:

Mary,Female,20,India
John,Male,26,Australia
Farook,Male,22,Afghanistan

So, the fields in my table should be id(auto-incremented),name,sex,age,country.

When I perform load data into my table with above structure, the result is:

id   Name   Gender     Age        Country
1   Female   20     India
2   Male     26     Australia
3   Male     22     Afghanistan

I mean, the last column is empty and the other columns take its positions in a column to its left. Hope you got it. Ans?